Segmentation fault (core dumped) while runnning PSFEx
I had a catalogue of sources extracted by Sextractor from the CEERS field. I selected few sources (approximately 10 (which have high snr and class_star value)) and create a fits ldac file and ran PSFEx on this new fits file I produced , But I got Segmentation fault (core dumped) error
> WARNING: This executable has been compiled using a version of the ATLAS library without support for multithreading. Performance will be degraded.

----- PSFEx 3.24.2 started on 2024-08-15 at 18:57:34 with 12 threads

----- 1 input catalogues:
Segmentation fault (core dumped)

when I ran PSFEx using the initial fits_ldac file I got from Sextractor , it is working and giving output.
> WARNING: This executable has been compiled using a version of the ATLAS library without support for multithreading. Performance will be degraded.

----- PSFEx 3.24.2 started on 2024-08-15 at 18:37:05 with 12 threads

----- 1 input catalogues:
catalogue.cat       :  "no ident        "    1 extension   11044 detections

   filename      [ext] accepted/total samp. chi2/dof FWHM ellip. resi. asym.
catalogue                    6/6       1.20   0.26   3.05  0.12  0.28  0.43
> All done (in 0.0 s)

can somebody give me an insight of why this happens?

run it in a debugger (e.g. gdb), get a backtrace and use that to talk to the developers of the software. A segmentation fault is often indicative of faulty memory access, i.e. read or write beyond bounds (or could be caused by faulty hardware)

The only obvious possibility is that there's something wrong with your new ldac fits file, something that PSFEx's file-reading or file-processing code can't handle. Since the full catalog file was processed OK, it's unlikely to be a hardware problem.

@Walker If you solved your problem could you flesh out your solution (from your comment) and post it as an answer for future reference?

I resolved it by creating a copy of the fits file and then using the update mode in fits.
# Create a copy of the original FITS file
shutil.copy2(original_file, copy_file)

# Open the copied FITS file in update mode
with fits.open(copy_file, mode='update') as hdul: 

